# Implementing search in a fragment recycler view android not working

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, searchview

I am trying to implement search in my fragment but its not working. no results shown up with search text. Also all the items are gone from the view when search text is removed and does not load the items on clicking menu item again from bottom navigation bar. I am very new to android development and struggling with searchview
Please suggest the solutions. TIA
here is my code

fragment.java

```
public class Cust_Home extends Fragment{

    RecyclerView recview_cust;
    DatabaseReference data;
    Adap cust_adapter;
    ArrayList<model> cust_menu;


    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public Cust_Home() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static Cust_Home newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Cust_Home fragment = new Cust_Home();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cust__home, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        recview_cust = v.findViewById(R.id.Cust_menu);
        data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FoodMenu");
        recview_cust.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recview_cust.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        cust_menu = new ArrayList<>();
        cust_adapter = new Adap(getContext(),cust_menu);
        recview_cust.setAdapter(cust_adapter);

        data.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){



                    model md = dataSnapshot.getValue(model.class);
                    cust_menu.add(md);
                }
                cust_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        return v;

    }

    


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu,menu);
           MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
           //SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
           SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
           searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
               @Override
               public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                   return false;
               }

               @Override
               public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                   cust_adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                   return false;
               }
           }) ;


        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }


}
```

Adapter class

```
public class Adap extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adap.myViewholder> implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    List<model> list;
    List<model> listfull;

    public Adap(Context context, List<model> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.listfull= new ArrayList<>(list);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.singleitem,parent,false);
        return new myViewholder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewholder holder, int position) {

        model m = list.get(position);
        holder.fooditem.setText(m.getFoodItem());
        holder.price.setText("$"+m.getFoodPrice());
        holder.chefName.setText(m.getChefName());
        holder.cheflocation.setText(m.getChefAddress());


        //holder.ing.setText(m.getFoodIngredients());
        Glide.with(holder.img.getContext()).load(m.getImage()).into(holder.img);
     
        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity)v.getContext();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,new Food_Details(m.getFoodItem(),m.getFoodDesc(),m.getFoodIngredients(),m.getImage(),m.getFoodPrice(),m.getFoodCal(),m.getChefName(),m.getItemID(),m.getUserid(),m.getChefPhoneNumber())).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filterdata;
    }

    private Filter filterdata =new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String searchText = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            List<model>templist = new ArrayList<>();
            if(searchText.length()==0 || searchText.isEmpty()){

                templist.addAll(listfull);
            }
            else {

                for ( model item:listfull){
                    if(item.getFoodItem().toLowerCase().contains(searchText)){

                        templist.add(item);
                    }

                }
            }
            FilterResults filterresults = new FilterResults();
            filterresults.values = templist;

            return filterresults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filterresults) {
            list.clear();
            list.addAll((Collection<? extends model>) filterresults.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };


    public static class myViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView fooditem, price,chefName,cheflocation;
        ImageView img;
        //ImageButton delete;


        public myViewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            fooditem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodname);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodprice);
            chefName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodchef);
            //desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodesc);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodimageurl);
            cheflocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodlocation);

           


        }
    }

}
```

menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

I also added  below code in my activity.class

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In `performFiltering` does the `tempList` end up having anything when you send a search that would normally return at least 1 item?

Comment: I tried debugging and templist size is zero. Also my ArrayList listall size is zero. it means its not initializing from the Arraylist list. How can I fix this.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: its working now. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Your `listfull` is empty because you initialize it with an empty list.

A simple fix would be to have  set function in the `Adapter`.

```
//in Adap
public void setFullList(List<String> list){
   this.listfull = list;
}

@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

      for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
          model md = dataSnapshot.getValue(model.class);
          cust_menu.add(md);
      }
      cust_adapter.setFullList(new ArrayList<>(cust_menu));
      cust_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the solution. This fixed my search functionality but I got another issue that after loading the app if i click on the home fragment again from my bottom navigation bar, it closes the app. Could you suggest something

Comment: How many items are in the full list?

Comment: on page load its same as size of list. But on clicking on home fragment again its size is same but data is null.

Comment: ```data.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){

                    model md = dataSnapshot.getValue(model.class);
                    cust_menu.add(md);
                }
                cust_adapter.setFullList(new ArrayList<>(cust_menu));
                cust_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }```  I kept this in my fragment.java

Comment: I mean the actual size like a count.

Comment: its just 5 records, so size is 5

Comment: allAll() was not working fine in copying the arraylist to another arraylist. So i changed it and it worked. Thankyou for the Solution :)